# prove $(t+1)^x+(t-1)^x-2t^x>0$ for any e: $x$ and any $t>1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

for any $x$ and for any $t>1$ prove this inequality:
$$
g(t,x)=(t+1)^x+(t-1)^x-2t^x>0.
$$
I know that for $x=0$ and $x=1$ we have $g(t,0)=g(t,1)=0$.
For the first integers like $t=2$ the solution is $x>1/2$, because the derivate of the function $g(2,x)$ is positive in $x=1$. How can I prove that the solution is $x>1$ for any $t>1$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(y)=y^x$ is a convex function for $x<0$ and $x>1$ so for every $y_1<y_2$ and $s\in [0,1]$ you have that

$f(s y_1+(1-s)y_2)<sf(y_1)+(1-s)f(y_2)$

but if you consider

$y_1:=t-1$

$y_2:=t+1$

$s=\frac{1}{2}$

you have that

$(\frac{1}{2}(t-1)+\frac{1}{2}(t+1))^x<\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^x+\frac{1}{2}(t+1)^x$

and so

$t^x<\frac{1}{2}[(t-1)^x+(t+1)^x]$

$2t^x<(t-1)^x+(t+1)^x$

For $x=0$ and $x=1$  does not true the inequality.

For $0<x<1$ the function $f(y)=y^x$ changed concavity and so it is true the inequality

$(t-1)^x+(t+1)^x<2t^x$

Comment: $f(y)=y^x$ is not convex for $x\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Take $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Is $f(y)=\sqrt{y}$ convex for $y>1$?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Thanks for answering... but the function $y^x$ is not convex for every $x$.

Comment: Ooopss you have reason, i think that the function is dependent from $x$ and $y$ fixed, but it is the inverse!

Comment: Anyway, your answer can be easily completed. Indeed, you are correct if $x<0$ or $x>1$. If $x=0$ and $x=1$ it is trivially false. If $x\in (0,1)$ then all your inequalities are reversed since you have strict concavity in place of strict convexity, so in this case the inequality is false as well. In conclusion, OP's inequality holds if and only if $x>1$ or $x<0$.

Comment: P.S. 'you have reason' does not exist in english ;)

Comment: You are right!!! Fortunately there is google translate. Thanks you for your correction Lorenzo ;)